# Search Functionality in Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I'm building Alexa skill that plays audios. An audio has a title, speakers and other properties.

**Problem**: I want to add search functionality in my skill, so that user may play audio on base of title or speaker's name etc. How can i achieve this?

**How can a user search on base of some custom string (speaker, title) & that string is passed to my skill?**, where i'll write logic to search that audio.

I know about custom intents and slots, but i don't know how they will work in my case.

Please guide. I just need some starting point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - it's [custom slots](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/defining-the-voice-interface#h2_speech_input) that you need to look at.

#### Your `intents.json`

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "GetAudio",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Query",
          "type": "QUERY"
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

#### Your defined Utterances

Your utterances might then include things like:

```
GetAudio search for {Query}
GetAudio find audio matching {Query}
```

#### Processing requests in your skill

When your skill receives the intent, it will get an [IntentRequest](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-standard-request-types-reference#intentrequest)
 full of any slots you've defined. So if you've defined a custom slot of `Query` (and ideally populated with example searches to improve the matching) as above, you might receive something like:

```
{
  "type": "IntentRequest",
    ...
  "intent": {
    "name": "GetAudio",
    "slots": {
      "Query": {
        "name": "Query",
        "value": "jimi hendrix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so it's then easy to retrieve the `value` field and use your internal logic to search.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You do it by defining a custom slot of type AMAZON.SearchQuery.
All details [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery)